# git pull --recurse-submodules ‘Could not access submodule’

Tags: git, git-submodules

When I run the `git pull --recurse-submodules` command, I get the error below:

```
Fetching submodule themes/
Could not access submodule ‘assets/vendor/bootstrap’
Errors during submodule fetch:
themes/
```

-- I am using - git version 2.27.0.windows.1
-- I'm Working with GitHub.

Could anyone please tell me why this error and how to fix it?

Comment: Can you please edit the question to include the version of `git` that you are using and also which `repo hosting platform/repo manager` you're working with such as github, gitlab etc. It'll help folks to answer it.

Comment: do you have access to submodule "assets/vendor/bootstrap"? (from the remote repostory, e.g. GitHub)

Comment: Hi Daemon, how do I know if I have access to the submodule

Comment: Hi! Are you sure that there are no other lines after the last line you pasted, `themes/` ?, also you could add the `git-submodules` tag to your question.

Comment: Yes, after the word themes/() -> the brackets have the company name.